# How to change file permissions after FTP from Linux

Tags: linux, file-copy, sftp

I have a source file server on Linux. The file permissions are set to 600 on this server. I have a Windows server that is downloading some of these files using SFTP and trying to view them. However, they are getting the obvious 'permission denied' error, because Windows user is different from the Linux user.
I don't want to change the umask on the Linux server to accommodate the requests from this only one particular windows server. Is there anything I can do so that the files are readable by the windows user? The person using the windows box can acquire administrative privileges on that box.

Comment: FTP?  SFTP over SSH or FTP with TLS?  What daemon is the windows system connecting to?

Comment: Since you use SFTP, it's fair to assume that the Windows user has an account on the Linux server. Perhaps Linux file ACLs are the solution: Keep the permissions at 600, but add a read ACL for that user. The command is `setfacl -m u:$USERNAME:r $FILE`. To automatically set ACLs when new files are created in a directory, I believe you can set a *default ACL* on that directory.

Comment: Another solution, somewhat complementing the *umask*, could be the [SETGID bit on directories](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html).

Comment: It is SFTP over SSH. The windows user has an account on the Linux server. Let me try that.

Comment: Let me read up on SETGID bit.